# RewriteRule to preserve querystring

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, qsa

I'm trying to make a redirect rule which follows this logic:

```
source: www.site.com/businessinfo.asp?accommID=123
destination: www.site.com/redirect.php?type=property&id=123
```

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^/businessinfo.asp$ /redirect.php?type=property&id=$1 [QSA]
```

I've tried a dozen different variations, but can't get anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /businessinfo\.asp\?accommID=(.*)\ HTTP 
RewriteRule ^ /redirect.php?type=property&id=%2 [R,L]
```

it should redirect `www.site.com/businessinfo.asp?accommID=123` to `www.site.com/redirect.php?type=property&id=123`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above. For future reference, we solved this with a simple one-liner...

```
Redirect 301 /businessinfo.asp http://www.site.com/redirect.php
```

The querystring appends anyway, so we just rewrote the redirect script slightly to deal with accommID instead of ID.